# When opening HDR images with Gimp, why does Levels show no light and dark values?

Tags: gimp, hdr, color-depth

I have some `.HIF` files taken using a Canon EOS R6 in HDR PQ mode. They are HEIC-encoded, HEIF-formatted files using the "heix" brand.

When I open them in Gimp 2.10.24, I am asked whether to convert the colour profile:

[image: import dialogue]

Regardless of whether I select Keep or Convert using any of the "rendering intent" choices, I end up with levels that look like this:

[image: levels dialogue]

i.e. there are no light or dark values in the histogram.

The Auto Import Levels button seems to make the right adjustment to set the black and white points to the lowest and highest tones respectively.

Shouldn't the image be imported with black and white points already set to these levels?

I am a total novice at working in high bit depths so I may have misunderstood something fundamental about what is going on here.

Comment: A histogram always expands so the point with 'most data' hits the top of the scale. It is not a set of absolute values. You have 'a lot' of mid-grey, so that's going to preventyou seeing the areas with black or white. We'd need to also see the photo to be able to tell precisely why that is, but 'mid-grey' is what any DSLR will aim for unless told otherwise. [I don't know exactly how Canon does this, I'm a Nikon shooter].

Comment: The images aren't supposed to have a lot of mid-greys. The identical scene shot in 8-bit JPEG mode doesn't have this issue.

Comment: We'd need to see the image to know. You're trying to HDR from a single shot, which is a computational function. Sometimes, the computer gets it wrong. You might do better bracketing shots & processing in post… or use a modern smart-phone - they have way more computational power than a dedicated camera [unfortunately;)) [btw, work in the camera's profile & only convert at export… fewer mistakes that way, most especially if you don't have a fully-calibrated workflow.]

Comment: I haven't worked with HEIC or HEIF really, but I notice that the source profile mentions "sRGB TRC" which is "sRGB tone response curve". The tiny preview in the corner of your screencap almost looks like an image with a "linear response curve" applied instead of the more "parabolic" one that is sRGB-TRC. No idea if this is true nor if it is helpful, but perhaps an avenue to investigate